# how to enable google service in google console

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I enabled this api but i got this error in my ionic app

```
**https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyAU1ymBJwG6sscjWS0Po4bP_yw4YQa-2SY 400 Bad Request**
```

please suggest me what is wrong there.

Comment: Can you dump the http request to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion and 400 response in firebug?

Comment: when i call this api i got like this response:   {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED"
 }
}

Comment: @mxlse what is your suggestion on Harish Mahajan reply? Kindly share. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your error message the problem is probably the following:

> **auth/operation-not-allowed**
>
> Thrown if the type of account corresponding
>   to the credential is not enabled. Enable the account type in the
>   Firebase Console, under the Auth tab.

For example if you use `signInAnonymously()` you also have to enable anonymous authentication in your firebase console. So check your firebase console configuration.